# How do I convert hex string into signed integer?

Tags: c#, .net, integer, hex, signed

I'm getting a hex string that needs to be converted to a signed 8-bit integer.  Currently I'm converting using Int16/Int32, which will obviously not give me a negative value for an 8-bit integer.  If I get the value 255 in Hex, how do I convert that to -1 in decimal?  I assume I want to use an sbyte, but I'm not sure how to get that value in there properly.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Comment: related and with great answers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275440/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-hex-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to put the first take the first 8 bits of the 16 bit integer and store them in an sbyte.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`Convert.ToSByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5ss9sbw.aspx)

For example:

```
string x = "aa";
sbyte v = Convert.ToSByte(x, 16);
// result: v = 0xAA or -86
```

You can also use [`sbyte.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d689fk6x(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example:

```
string y = "bb";
sbyte w = sbyte.Parse(y, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
// result: w = 0xBB or -69
```

To answer your question about the upper or lower byte of an Int16:

```
string signed_short = "feff";

// Truncate 16 bit value down to 8 bit
sbyte b1 = (sbyte)Convert.ToInt16(signed_short, 16);
sbyte b2 = (sbyte)short.Parse(signed_short, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
// result: b1 = 0xFF or -1
// result: b2 = 0xFF or -1

// Use upper 8 bit of 16 bit
sbyte b3 = (sbyte)(Convert.ToInt16(signed_short, 16) >> 8);
sbyte b4 = (sbyte)(short.Parse(signed_short, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) >> 8);
// result: b3 = 0xFE or -2
// result: b4 = 0xFE or -2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform an `unchecked` cast, like this:

```
sbyte negativeOne = unchecked((sbyte)255);
```

Comment: I guess, it is because OP was asking to convert "STRING into signed integer". Anyway, your answer was helpful to me. Thank you! :)