# How to Convert Hex String to Hex Number

Tags: c#, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert hex string into signed integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705429/how-do-i-convert-hex-string-into-signed-integer)

example:"3A" convert to 0x3A,thanks a lot!

Comment: This question is closed as exact duplicate, however the situation and also the answer is different. also the other question [How do I convert hex string into signed integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705429/how-do-i-convert-hex-string-into-signed-integer) does not have answer. this one has an accepted answer.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the linked one. The linked question says "If I get the value 255 in Hex, how do I convert that to -1 in decimal?" In this question, given "255", the OP would want 0x255, not -1.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
Convert.ToInt32("3A", 16)
```

Answer (score 48):

```
int.Parse("3A",NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

or

```
long.Parse("3A",NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

etc...

Comment: thanks a lot!!!continue...I'm trying to convert a string "3A" to a byte[0]=0x3A,and I really dont know how to do...

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321370/convert-hex-string-to-byte-array