# C# Parse string to int

Tags: c#

I have a program where I hard read some offsets, right now the offsets are hard coded in my code like this:

```
public static int VecViewOffset = 0x00000104;
public static int VecPunch = 0x00002FF8;
```

But what I would like to do is to read these offsets from a .ini / .txt file so I do not have to change the offsets in in my code which I did. How ever, I read the offset as a string from the file and I need to parse it to and int. But it doesn't work.

This is how I am trying to do it.

```
public int GetInt(string section, string key)
{
    var keyValue = SettingsData[section][key];
    var setting = int.Parse(keyValue);
    return setting;
}
```

I can parse "12" to and in just fine, but I can't parse "0x00000104" to and int Any ideas? .

Comment: You need to use `NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier`

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275440/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-hex-number

Comment: @juharr Thanks i'll look into that.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson Actually reading the documentation closely it says it doesn't allow the "0x" prefix, so if you do use that I think you'd have to drop the prefix in your file.

Comment: This will work: Convert.ToInt32("0x00000104", 16), returns 260