# C# how to perse Hex string to int

Tags: c#, string, int, hex

As title says, how to get same hex value from string to int so I can procces it.

```
String a = "075abc";
int b; // I want int b to have same 075abc
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);

//on compile i want result like 
//075abc
//075abc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert hex string into signed integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705429/how-do-i-convert-hex-string-into-signed-integer)

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
// Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer.
int b = Convert.ToInt32(a, 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Convert.ToInt32()` overload that receives the string and the base:

```
String a = "075abc";
int b = Convert.ToInt32(a, 16);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to prints integers in hexadecimal representation you can do it calling `ToString()` with `"x"` or `"X"` as format:

```
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("x"));
```

Comment: int is returned as 32961, however i want int to be same 075abc. Is that possible?

Comment: @Dudeson: you should note that `075abc` and `32961` is the same value, `"075abc"` and `"32961"` is how you represent the number in one base or another, by default numbers are represented in decimal base.