# Signed hex string to integer

Tags: c#, .net-core, hex

I have a signed hex string `FFFF` which is signed. So when I convert it to an integer it should be -1. But when I use `int.Parse`/`int.TryParse` or `System.Convert.ToInt32` it gives me the value `65535`.

```
var rawValue = int.Parse("FFFF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
// rawValue = 65535
```

```
var rawValue = Convert.ToInt32("FFFF", 16);
// rawValue = 65535
```

Any ideas how I can get the parse/convert functions to recognise its a signed hex string?

Comment: FFFF is 65535 Int32 so... Are you asking "is there some type like `System.Int16` which normally called `short` in other languages?"

Comment: I think there is an answer to your question in this post [this post ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705429/how-do-i-convert-hex-string-into-signed-integer)

Comment: I thought there might be some way to indicate to the conversion function that the hex was "signed". So it would recognise that hex strings starting "FF..." were going to be negative. Something to do with twos compliment?

Answer (score 2):

`FFFF` is -1 if it is converted to 16 bit signed integer.
So you can try;

```
var x = Int16.Parse("FFFF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); // x will be -1
```

If you convert it to 32 bit (which is what `int.Parse` does) it will be 65535 because sign bit will be 0

```
var x = Int32.Parse("FFFF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); // x will be 65535
```